# Replacement for Spring's AbstractCommandController

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm trying to learn Spring MVC from Spring In Action 2nd Edition (Covers Spring 2.0).

My IDE tells me that `AbstractCommandController` has been deprecated.  Has it been replaced?  What is the recommended way of handling cases for which one would have extended `AbstractCommandController`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Spring 3.0, the entire `Controller` hierarchy has been deprecated and replaced by the annotation-style of controllers. This makes things considerably simpler, you no longer have to worry about which of the various base classes to extend.

In fact, you won't even find mention of the old hierarchy in the Spring reference manual any more, just the [new annotation-style](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-controller).

Annotated controllers perform the same functionality as `AbstractCommandController` by simple auto-binding of method parameters, e.g.

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping
    public String handleMe(Command command) {
       ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like the javadoc of `AbstractCommandController` says:

> @deprecated as of Spring 3.0, in favor of annotated controllers

So, look at the [spring reference documentation for annotated controllers](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-annotation).

Answer (score 2):

Your book covers Spring 2.0 which relies on subclasses of the `AbstractCommandController`. In Spring 2.5 the equivalent of an `AbstractCommandController` is the `AbstractController`. In Spring 3.0 (as others have pointed out) the equivalent is a properly annotated `@Controler` class.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://earldouglas.com/posts/spring-mvc.html) is an example of annotation-based Spring MVC that might help get you started.