# AbstractCommadController removed in Spring 4.0.6

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Hi i was upgrading my spring jars to spring 4.0.6. I found that AbstractCommandController is removed from this version i would like to know the alternatives to this controller.

Comment: this link might help:-

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604154/replacement-for-springs-abstractcommandcontroller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AbstractCommandController was deprecated in Spring 3.0 and it is removed in Spring 4.0.6 version so your compilation fails.

refer this link for workaround

[Replacement for Spring's AbstractCommandController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604154/replacement-for-springs-abstractcommandcontroller)

Answer (score 1):

AbstractCommandController was deprecreated as of Spring 3.0.  Since you're upgrading to Spring 4.0.6, you'll need to use the Controller or RestController annotation style instead.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-controller